# how to password protect a website hosted on gunicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

Is there a way to password protect an application which is hosted in gunicorn,

I did this with .htaccess in apache, but can we do this in gurnicorn?

Comment: You should be using a proxy (such as nginx) to pass requests onto gunicorn. In that situation, you can do authentication through nginx. See here http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/

Comment: @pastylegs Thanks for the suggestion, right now haven't configured nginx, will try that out. Thanks

Comment: The comment by @TimmyO'Mahony should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @PhilippZedler I completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged [django](/questions/tagged/django) and it has some useful things built right into it...

You should be able to do a [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) right before your specific view funciton.

This will force the current 'anonymous' user to a login screen if they aren't logged in.

Comment: sorry if my description was not clear, here I don't even want to show my website unless you the the right login and password.

Comment: i don't understand how my solution doesn't provide you with what you're looking for (assuming you're using Django as it is tagged). If you include `@login_required` on all of your views, it will not let the person see your website... it will direct them to a login screen. Since every view requires a login, if they do not give a proper one, they will not be allowed to view the website... Practically, there is no difference between apache's .htaccess restriction login popup and a webpage auth scheme (except more to 'manage' using the htaccess scheme)

Comment: Yes there is a difference. Using HTTP auth will stop the user before their request gets passed onto the application server meaning they can do very little. Anything implemented via Gunicorn means the user is at the application level and can access all its potential holes. Furthermore, I imagine the OP wants to be able to work on the application while still having a protective layer around it to stop people snooping. It would be very annoying to have to add login decorators to views that won't be required once the app is live

Comment: i understand there is a difference between what a restrictive .htaccess file does and application level auth, but my solution still would work. You would still have a protective layer so long as the person doing the work is logged in. It's not that annoying to do login decorators... a simple `#`... you're talking roughly 10 seconds editing one file to make it production... not exactly that annoying for what it gives you...

Comment: Adding a proxy is much more involved and requires more technical knowledge to get right. KISS = adding one line above the views to force a login...

Comment: @g19fanatic Adding [at]login_required to all the views means altering the actual flow of the application, I have some pages in my application which have to behave differently when a user is logged-in. Also, I have more than 100 views in my project, adding [at]login_required may not be feasible. Also, I used .htaccess to do this trick in case of apache, I recently started using gunicorn, So, wanted to use the same with gunicorn

Answer (score 1):

You can also use middleware and for example kill every session and show nothing if it  not passes the requirements. For example, you can define middleware which checks if the request comes from the IP you use, if yes - do nothing, if no - stop. Maybe not the best, but solution :)

Comment: I think this is a good middleground between view-based login and a dedicated proxy/server with HTTP auth